# Camera following program

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D platformer, and I want the camera to follow the character once it gets to the center, but follow it only on the x axis. I've downloaded this code, and it worked, but it followed the character on both the x and the y, and it stuck the character in the same corner of the camera that it started. I tried to add an if statement so that the camera only started moving once the offset was equal to the player, but it didn't work. I got the error code 'cannot implicitly convert vector3 to bool'

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CompleteCameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;


    private Vector3 offset;

    void Start () 
    {
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

    void LateUpdate () 
    {
        if (offset == player.transform.position)
        {
            transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know c#, but in other languages you need `==` when comparing values, single `=` being the assignment operator.

Comment: Yeah, you do. I tried both, and evidently I copied it when it was set to the single =. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is ok and doesn't throw an error (in the current version). Anyway ... are you sure you only want to move the camera if the offset is **exactly** what it was at start? Basically it will never be called because the player probably will never again reach the same position again ....

Comment: This was also solved multiple times already just have a look [here](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-ufo-tutorial/following-player-camera) or [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/878913/how-to-get-camera-to-follow-player-2d.html) or [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/29183/2d-camera-smooth-follow.html) .. for only the X-axis just do `position.x` instead of `position`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation seems to suggest that what you are doing is fine. But perhaps your code could be modified to fit this example? My gut says that this is going to give you the same error, but it could be worth trying.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html

```
 using UnityEngine; 
 using System.Collections;

 public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour 
 {
     public Transform other;

     void Example()
     {
         if (other && transform.position == other.position)
         {
             print("I'm at the same place as the other transform!");
         }
     }
 }
```

You could also try using the Vector3.Equals() method instead if you're ok with doing an exact comparison.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Equals.html

You could also try implementing your own function to compare the two vectors.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/395513/vector3-comparison-efficiency-and-float-precision.html

I really can't see anything wrong with the code you've posted, is it possible the error exists in another file?

Comment: The error only occurs with that file, when I comment out the if statement the error goes away.

Comment: Hmm, the error itself is suggesting that the return value you get from the == operator is giving back a Vector3, which cannot be implicitly cast to the Boolean value that the if statement is expecting. Could you try wrapping the offset == player.transform.position in an explicit cast?

Comment: Also, what version of Unity are you using?

Comment: Based on the research I've done and your code, offset is a Vector3 and player.transform.position is also a Vector3. Therefore we know that the == operator can be applied to these variables. We know that it also returns a Boolean value so no implicit cast should even be necessary when doing this comparison in the if() statement. Though it is worth noting that C# does not allow implicit casting. There is no other code here that could be the cause of your error. Maybe Unity has fallen asleep at the wheel have you tried restarting it?

Comment: Yes I have. I'm using unity 2018. Im currently making do with the one without the if statement. Hopefully I can hit my head against the code 'till it works.